# Bound on $|f(x)|$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

The problem states that:

> If $f$ is a real valued, twice differentiable function and satisfies the equation: 
>   $$f(x) + f''(x) = -xg(x)f'(x),$$
>   where $g(x)\geq 0$ for all real values of $x$. Prove that $|f(x)|$ is bounded.

My approach till now :
adding $f'(x)$ on both sides of equation, we get
$$f(x) + f''(x) + f '(x) = f '(x)[1-xg(x)]$$

Now consider $h(x) = 1-xg(x)$. If $x<0$, $h(x)>1$ [since $g(x)$ is always non negative] and if $x>0$, $h(x)<1$.

So let us consider 2 cases:

(I) If $x>0$ then
$$f(x) + f''(x) + f'(x) >f'(x)$$
on solving this equation, we get that $f(x) \geq -f''(x)$.

(II) If $x<0$ then
$$f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x) <f '(x)$$
on solving we get, $f(x)\leq -f''(x)$.

From results of both cases it comes out that , 
$$-f''(x)\leq f(x)\leq -f''(x)$$ 
which means that $f(x) = -f''(x)$, which is not what we had to prove.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the edits @Robert Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply with $2f'(x)$ and integrate
$$
f'(x)^2+f(x)^2=f'(0)^2+f(0)^2-2x^2\int_0^1sg(sx)f'(sx)^2ds
$$
The last term is always negative, so that $f'(x)^2+f(x)^2$ is bounded which implies the claim.

Comment: I think the limit in the last integral should be from 0 to 'x' isnt it ? Because you integrated the LHS of the equation from 0 to x . I did not understand how you introduced 's' in the last integral.

Comment: No, it is correct. I parametrized the segment from $0$ to $x$ as $s\mapsto sx$, $s\in[0,1]$. This is a quite standard segment parametrization, $s\mapsto (1-s)A+sB$ runs through the segment from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: I still did not understand..how did the x^2 term came out of the integral..from where can i 
learn more about these parametrizations ?

Comment: It comes from the factor $x$ and the parametrization of the integral, $\int_0^1(sx)\,g(sx)f'(sx)^2\,d(sx)$.

Comment: OKay got it ! Thank you @Lutz Lehmann